# Probability density function in given interval?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

A probability density function on the interval $[a,1]$ is given by $1/x^2$ and outside this interval the value of the function is zero. The value of $a$ is_____ .

---

Somewhere it explain as:

$$\int _a^1\:\frac{1}{x^2}dx=1$$

$$\implies a=0.5$$

> Can you explain in formal way, please. Why we equating with one?

Comment: Since it's a probability density function, you must have, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is the pdf of a random variable on some interval $[a,b]$, then
$$
\int_a^b p(x)\ dx=1.
$$
In this case $p(x)=1/x^2$ and $b=1$. Thus we get $1/a-1=1$, so $a=1/2$.